# Wagmi pass dynamic argument

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, web3js, wagmi

[image]

here I want to pass argument in `withdrawWrite` function where I am generating sign in one function call but it is not taking any argument and I can't directly pass in hook because I can't use hook inside my function.

[image]

I am using "wagmi": "^1.4.5"

Thanks in advance